Help with a derivation problem
I am having trouble with this derivation. if anyone could help me that would be great
~T->(~P → ~R). (R → (~T → P)) → (~Q → ~S). ~S → (~Q → S) therefore Q

~T->(~P->~R)
(R->(~T->P))->(~Q->~S)
~S->(~Q->S)
Well, we can first try to simplify these annoyingly complicated premises by expanding out the implications A -> B into ~A v B.
The first premise: ~T->(~P->~R) = T v P v ~R
The second premise. (R->(~T->P))->(~Q->~S) = (R -> (T v P))->(Q v ~S) = (~R v T v P)->(Q v ~S) = ~(T v P v ~R) v Q v ~S, where I rearranged the order of (~R v T v P) to match the order in the first premise.
For the third premise. ~S->(~Q->S) = S v (~Q->S) = S v Q v S = Q v S
So from here a proof strategy is clear. Combine T v P v ~R with ~(T v P v ~R) v Q v ~S, and we find Q v ~S must be true. But we also have Q v S. Since either S or ~S is false, the only way for Q v ~S and Q v S to be both true is if Q is true.
